# Error on sm display with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I unable to align the blocks horizontally on sm display  [min-width: 768px]

you might click image illustrating my display problem above and i pasted my html bloc also !

i need a help  !

```html
    <div  class="row">
           
            <div class="col-sm-4 border1gris text-center">
                <a href="{{ path('..') }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block"  src="img1" alt=""/><br>Text Text Text Text Text 
                </a>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 border1gris text-center">
                <a href="{{ path('..') }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img2" alt=""/><br>Text Text Text Text Text 
                </a>
            </div>
      
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 border1gris text-center">
                <a href="{{ path('..') }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img3" alt=""/><br>Text Text Text Text Text 
                </a>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you add more detail of your code with a jsfiddle, this can help us to help you with your problem.

Comment: We need your CSS files to see what are you applying to these elements. Most likely `border1gris` is creating a border which makes the third column collapse to the third row.

Comment: this is  my result on web page  : [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdz49.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that your code snippet above works properly

Comment: thanx a lot for your reaction , i 'm providing you a complete example with a jsfiddle , my link: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23536/

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to your issue, 
Please check this link.
**https://jsfiddle.net/hu4qLy4n/**

**Changes in HTML**

```
    <a href="#">
    <div class="img-container3">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" alt="" />
  </a>
```

**Changes in CSS**

```
.img-container1{
  width:249px;
    height: 200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  }
.img-container1 img{
  width:100%;
}  
.img-container2{
  width:200px;
   height: 263px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  }
.img-container2 img{
  width:100%;
}  
.img-container3{
  width:249px;
  height: 281px;  
  margin:0 auto;
  }
.img-container3 img{
  width:100%;
}
```

*Try to avoid giving height to the images, also try to put the images ins side a container. Container must be your needed width, and images should be in 100% width.*

Comment: thank your for response Aswin, but my problem is not resolved because the three gray block are not aligned on sm bootstrap display.

Comment: Can you show me the updated code 
let me try to resolve it.